# R - how to: for every word in a certain list , count how often the word occurs in a column of eg 3000 words

Tags: r, string, loops, counting, grepl

I have a dataset x with a bunch of text `(columns: title, location, contents)` in about 3000 rows.

EDIT: an example.

title    |     location       |       contents
...             DUBAI                     ....
...             DUBAI                     ....
...             KHARTOUM                  ....
...             KHARTOUMSUDAN             ....
...             JAKARTA                   ....

[link to image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yccS2.png)

I have a list of locations. `locations <- c("DUBAI", "KHARTOUM", "JAKARTA", "Paris")`.

Now I want to make a loop that'll start with Dubai and see in how many columns it occurs and then create a variable with the count for that. and then i want to move onto the next word in the locations list `(Khartoum)` and do the same thing.

So in this case I would expect to see: Dubai = 2, Khartoum = 2, Jakarta = 1.

I have this so far, but I don't know how to generalize it and make it into a loop:

```
numberDUBAI <- nrow(dplyr::filter(x, grepl(' DUBAI ', location)))
```

and then I repeat it for each word

```
numberLOCATIONS <- c(numberDUBAI, numberKHARTOUM, numberJAKARTA, numberPARIS)
```

but this feels very inefficient, help? :D

Comment: Use table() function. It gives you the frequency of each word.

Answer (score 4):

We can do this with `tidyverse` using `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(locations, ~
               x %>%
                  summarise(n = sum(str_detect(location, .x, ignore_case = TRUE)))
      )
```

NOTE: Assuming that 'x' is the dataset, 'location' is the column and from the OP's post 'locations' is a `vector` of patterns

Comment: Maybe you could use `toupper` (or `tolower`), the data seems messy.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  I think we can use the ignore_case` in `str_detect` as modifier

Comment: OP here, thanks!:
dataset is called: x
columns are: title, location, content
the list of words I want to it to look through one by one is: locations
however i don't quite understand what youre doing with the code and where the new variable is that counts how often the first location occurs in the dataset.

Comment: @JGreen  In the code, it is looping through the 'locations' vector of pattern, use `str_detect` to return a logical vector. Take the `sum` of TRUE values to get the count.  This will return a `list` of datasets

Comment: @JGreen BTW, you haven't provided any small reproducible example for others to help you better

Comment: @akrun I added a sort of example of code and what I expect the answer to be. The dataset I have has a looooot of text so it's kind of hard to paste that in.

Comment: @JGreen  Please use dput to show a small reproducible example.  We can't copy data from the images